# How do I center elements on a page on every device? iPad, iPhone, Desktop & any other device

Tags: html, css, layout, liquid, spacing

My [website's](https://synicalglobal.com) home page contains nav elements, social media icons under the nav, and a logo that lays on top of the nav elements with a gap. It could look perfect on mobile, but have the most atrocious gap on desktop, and

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
  src: url(https://static.wixstatic.com/ufonts/617a47_069dbc8c08b34b95bda387f5d2f9b534/woff2/file.woff2);
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
}

.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(100vh - 130px);
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

header#SiteHeader {
  display: none;
}

.btm-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: auto;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.btm-nav i {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.btm-nav h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
  margin: -2px 0px 0px;
}

a,
:active,
:hover,
:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.context-menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu-button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #3E3E3E;
}

.social-media-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.social-media-button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #0B0B0B;
  margin-right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: calc(25% - 1px);
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.social-media-button:hover {
  background-color: #363636;
}

.social-media-button i {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.social-media-button i {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

i.fa-brands.fa-discord {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.btm-nav-1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}

.btm-nav-1 {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.btm-nav-2 {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.btm-nav-3 {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.btm-nav-4 {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.logo-container img {
  max-width: 134px;
  max-height: 89%;
}

.btm-nav-1,
.btm-nav-2,
.btm-nav-3,
.btm-nav-4,
.btm-nav-5 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 0.05px solid #FFF;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 134px;
  height: 20px;
}

.btm-nav-1:hover,
.btm-nav-2:hover,
.btm-nav-3:hover,
.btm-nav-4:hover,
.btm-nav-5:hover {
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.social-link {
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script async src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/56070a7eed.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img class="syn-img" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0478/3144/9763/files/NEW-LOGO-WHITE_446478d2-abf7-4538-b217-fd695c815af8.png?v=1685297838" alt="Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="btm-nav">
    <div class="btm-nav-1">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h1>Button 1</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btm-nav-2">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h1>Button 2</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btm-nav-3">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h1>Button 3</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btm-nav-4">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <h1>Button 4</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="social-nav">
      <div class="social-link discordLink">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-discord" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="social-link instagramLink">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="social-link twitterLink">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="social-link tiktokLink">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

look even worse on some other LARGER screen. The problems I'm experiencing is the gap gets bigger and bigger the larger the viewport is. I can't keep making media queries for every single screen width. There has to be some way using something like flex or however you CSS magicians do it.

I've tried adding max-width and min-width queries to manually adjust the gap between the logo and nav elements on like 10 different screen sizes. All of which clearly did not work because I'm sitting here asking this question.

Comment: Hi, it's much easier for us to help you if you give a runnable snippet which shows the problem but doesn't include stuff that is not relevant to the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And what gap are you talking about - or do you just want the logo and text to get bigger on bigger screens?

Comment: @AHaworth I'd have to make a full liquid conversion, would a link to the site + a password work? I code inside of the shopify editor, so there isn't an HTML version of this site that matches what I have right now.
"Anyone with this link can access the preview within the next 2 days"
[link to site](https://p7wo81h8p6jcdsuu-65116831959.shopifypreview.com)

Comment: Linking to an outside site makes the question useless for future readers when the problem is solved so is no longer demonstrated. SO's aim is to build a library of questions and answers, not just to answer one person's question at a particular point in time. So I'm afraid you'll have to put i a bit of effort to isolate the problem (and with luck that might help you solve it!).

Comment: Roger that! I'll get on it :)

Comment: I've updated the post to contain the fully working code! @AHaworth

Comment: Thanks. So which gap are you worried about? Is it the one under the logo?

Comment: Yeah, under the logo. My monitor is only 1366x768 so I can't see how extreme it is, but i've debugged on screen sizes above 1080p, and it's awfully large. It takes away from the design so much. The entire rest of the site looks perfect on shopify, aside from the home page (the code I sent)

The gap gets larger the bigger the screen is. I had to make the gap larger than normal just so It would look normal on mobile. Without the dramatic addition to the gap, the logo was squished into the buttons and looked even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

- Removing the `height: calc(100vh - 130px);` from the `.logo-container` rule. This results in a height that has no bearing on the size of the `<img>` it contains, and as you have seen, results in a large gap on taller viewports.
- Removing the following properties from `.btn-nav`:

  ```css
  position: fixed;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  ```

  The fixed positioning of this element means that it is not in the natural layout flow of the document and becomes independent in positioning with the other elements on the page.
- Wrapping all your elements in another `<div>`, and then center it with a grid:

  ```html
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      …
    </div>
  </body>
  ```

  ```css
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  }
  ```

Full example:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
  src: url(https://static.wixstatic.com/ufonts/617a47_069dbc8c08b34b95bda387f5d2f9b534/woff2/file.woff2);
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
}

header#SiteHeader {
  display: none;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
  
.btm-nav {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.btm-nav i {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.btm-nav h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: IDIDNTSTEALTHIS;
  margin: -2px 0px 0px;
}

a,
:active,
:hover,
:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.context-menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu-button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #3E3E3E;
}

.social-media-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.social-media-button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #0B0B0B;
  margin-right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: calc(25% - 1px);
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.social-media-button:hover {
  background-color: #363636;
}

.social-media-button i {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.social-media-button i {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

i.fa-brands.fa-discord {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.btm-nav-1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}

.btm-nav-1 {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.btm-nav-2 {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.btm-nav-3 {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.btm-nav-4 {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.logo-container img {
  max-width: 134px;
  max-height: 89%;
}

.btm-nav-1,
.btm-nav-2,
.btm-nav-3,
.btm-nav-4,
.btm-nav-5 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 0.05px solid #FFF;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 134px;
  height: 20px;
}

.btm-nav-1:hover,
.btm-nav-2:hover,
.btm-nav-3:hover,
.btm-nav-4:hover,
.btm-nav-5:hover {
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.social-link {
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script async src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/56070a7eed.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <img class="syn-img" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0478/3144/9763/files/NEW-LOGO-WHITE_446478d2-abf7-4538-b217-fd695c815af8.png?v=1685297838" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="btm-nav">
      <div class="btm-nav-1">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <h1>Button 1</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="btm-nav-2">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <h1>Button 2</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="btm-nav-3">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <h1>Button 3</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="btm-nav-4">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <h1>Button 4</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="social-nav">
        <div class="social-link discordLink">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-discord" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="social-link instagramLink">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="social-link twitterLink">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="social-link tiktokLink">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. You are a LITERAL life saver. And I mean that as literally as possible. This was stressing me out in ways you can't even imagine. God bless you. Apparently I have some studying to do.

Comment: One quick thing I noticed. On my site, the navigation seems to be pinned to the top of the screen now. The code you provided works very well, however I can't seem to figure out why it's stuck to the top like that. You can find the site @ https://grimlabs.co/.  If you get prompted with a page with an input, click the lock icon and enter the password: "tonythetiger"